# OAuth2 over HTTPS enabled load balancer

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have OAuth2 working when using HTTP but I'm unable to get my OAuth working with HTTPS.  If I configure the OAuth2 server with a callback URL of HTTP://myauthserver/callback and access the client with HTTP then all works.  If I change both to HTTPS, it fails after validation of credentials with the callback URL in the browser.

I'm reasonably certain it is due to my network setup.

My setup has the SSL cert loaded on the Load Balancer with an HTTP connection between the load balancer and application server.

Anyone have suggestions on how to correctly configure OAuth2 to work with this network configuration?